# Username and password authentication for Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I am inserting and querying data to `Solr` using `solrj`.

I am using the following methods to save/query data.

```
SolrClient client = getSolrClient();
final Map<String, String> queryParamMap = new HashMap<>();
queryParamMap.put("q", "*:*");
queryParamMap.put("fl", "id, name");
MapSolrParams queryParams = new MapSolrParams(queryParamMap);
final QueryResponse response = client.query("testcore1", queryParams);
final SolrDocumentList documents = response.getResults();
```

--

```
final SolrClient client = getSolrClient();
final SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
doc.addField("name", "Amazon Kindle Paperwhite");
final UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.add("testcore1", doc);
client.commit("testcore1");
```

I have added username and password authentication for Solr. 
I changed the Solr client method and added `UsernamePasswordCredentials`

```
private SolrClient getSolrClient() {
        String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
        //return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder().withBaseSolrUrl(solrUrl).withHttpClient(client).build();
}
```

Still, it's showing the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8983/solr
```

How do I add authentication to these functions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem. For me using "ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient" solved the problem:

```
    public static SolrClient getUpdateClient() {
    SolrClient solrClient = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.Builder("http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:8983/solr")
      .build();
    return solrClient;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `HttpSolrClientFactory`, so method look like:

```java
private SolrClientFactory getClientFactory(final SolrClient client, String coreName) {
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
        env.getProperty("solr.user"), 
        env.getProperty("solr.password")
    );
    return new HttpSolrClientFactory(client, coreName, credentials, "BASIC");    
}

SolrClient client = getClientFactory(new HttpSolrClient(SOLR_URL), coreName).getSolrClient()
final Map<String, String> queryParamMap = new HashMap<>();
queryParamMap.put("q", "*:*");
queryParamMap.put("fl", "id, name");
MapSolrParams queryParams = new MapSolrParams(queryParamMap);
final QueryResponse response = client.query("testcore1", queryParams);
final SolrDocumentList documents = response.getResults();
```

Hope this help you !!

Comment: Note that HttpSolrClientFactory is a Spring artifact.